# Why 'begun' instead of 'began' in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-perfect

I read the following passage from the instagram account of a trans celebrity describing their romantic life pre/post-transition, and was a bit irked by the use of 'begun' (which is funny, because it meant the pathos of the entire post was lost on me...)

> I have not been successful as a lesbian. It’s a new problem for me. Before I transitioned women would somehow gravitate into my life without my having to think about it very much. In the first years of transition men begun to gravitate instead. I sometimes feel like I sacrificed my sexual orientation for my gender.

I get that the sentence is in present-perfect (*had begun*) but there is no 'had' here, and 'begun' is not functioning as a participle (*is begun*) - it sounds like an active verb. I thought perhaps 'to gravitate' would be considered the 'helping verb' (without which 'begun' would be 'began'), but 'began to gravitate' sounds fine too. Am I missing something or is it just an error on their part?

Comment: begun just does not work there/ Began or had begun. of course.

Comment: You may think of it as a dialect.  In standard English it would be "began."

Comment: I think it's just a typo for 'began'. As it's instagram no-one will have proofread  or check-read it.

Comment: Try not to let yourself get hung up on small grammatical details in online posts.

Comment: People make grammar and spelling errors all the time. Get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary notes that](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/begun#English) "begun" is sometimes used as the simple past of "begin," but it states that this usage is "obsolete or nonstandard."